# Parse JSON with GSON based on filed value (used with retrofit)

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I have two JSON objects with similar fields. The only difference is that the first one always has field

```
type: "type1"
```

And second can have anything in 'type' field except 'type1'.

I want them to be parsed into java objects with different classes (using classes FirstType.class and OtherType.class). Is it possible?

Object one:

```
{
    id: "1j23jr8swgs8"
    type: "type1"
}
```

Object two:

```
{
    id: "3sdaa3dq18"
    type: "unknown_type"
}
```

And java classes:

```
class FirstType
{
    String id;
}    

class OtherType
{
    String id;
}
```

Comment: Could you post full json?

Comment: We need more explanation to help you.

Comment: It's certainly possible, but the exact code depends on your json structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a heck of a long time since I used Gson, but it should look something like this:

```
//convert your json string into a json object
JsonElement element = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString);
JsonObject  object = element.getAsJsonObject();

//get the relevant value from your object
String result = object.get("type").toString();

//compare and convert accordingly
if (result.equals("type1")) {
    ObjectOne object = gson.fromJson(element, ObjectOne.class);
} else {
    ObjectTwo object = gson.fromJson(element, ObjectTwo.class);
}
```

Try this and see if it works!

Answer (score 2):

Google gson will work nicely here.

You can do something like this:-

```
class ObjectName {
String id;
String type;
}

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
ObjectName name = gson.fromJson(json, ObjectName.class);

FirstType firstType = null;
SecondType secondType = null;
if(name.type.equals("type1"))
firstType = new FirstType(name.id);
else
secondType = new SecondType(name.id);
```